# One person catch?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

> Starting from rest, a child throws a ball of mass m with an initial speed v , at an angle B with the horizontal direction. The child then chases after the ball, accelerating at a constant acceleration a . If the child wants to catch the ball at the same height as it was thrown, what must be the child's acceleration a ? Express your answer in terms of some or all of the variables v , m , B and g for the gravitational constant. Express the trigonometric functions in terms of the basic sin(B), cos(B) or tan(B).

Equations:
x(t)=X_0+v_0*t+1/2*g*t^2

Attempt at solution: 
Origin at launch point and t=0 when ball is thrown

x(t)=v*cos(B)*t
y(t)=v*sin(B)*t-1/2*g*t^2
The ball is caught at the same height y as launched so time in air: 0=v*sin(B)*t-1/2*g*t^2 and
0=t(v*sin(B)-1/2*g*t) t=(2*v*sin(B))/g

To find horizontal range: x(t)=(2*v^2*sin(B)*cos(B))/g

and x(t_child)=a so a=(2*v^2*sin(B)*cos(B))/g

Not sure what I'm doing wrong... Please help

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Also note, that equations should be set using MathJax, see [the help page on notation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

You got good answers until you stated:

> and x(t_child) = a

which is not true. It is hard for me to precisely say what went wrong in your thinking because there is no good notion $t_{\text{child}}$ to use here.

Instead, there is an $x_{\text{child}}(t)$. If the child has a constant acceleration $a$ then this will also follow the equation you quoted for the constant-acceleration of gravity, namely $$x_{\text{child}}(t) = \frac 12 ~a~ t^2 + v_{0,\text{child}} ~ t + x_{0,\text{child}} ~. $$You need to then solve for $a$ such that at some special time $t^*$ which you have already worked out, both of the following hold:$$\begin{array}{c}x_{\text{child}}(t^*) = x_{\text{ball}}(t^*) \\ y_{\text{ball}}(t^*) = y_{\text{child}}(t^*) = 0 \end{array}$$Does that help?

Comment: Of course... Not sure what I was thinking